# get value of the focus input text, concatenate it to data value, when click will get the result + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

first i make a function that when you focus it, it will display that index to an input type:text. next i make a p tag that when you click it , it will get the data-id value. Now i want to combine the result of the index value and the data-id value to my p tag that has the classname of 'result'. when i try to run it , it will display only the data-id value and not the index value. what seems to be wrong..click the jsfiddle link to see my code

```js
function inputFocus(evename){
  $(evename).each(function(index){
    $(this).focus(function(){
      inpIndex = index;
      $('.dispIndex').val(inpIndex);
      // console.log( jQuery.type(zim_index));
    })
  });
}

inputFocus('.input_index');
inputVal = $(".dispIndex").val();

$(".p_names").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
     dataId = $(this).data('id');
     resultHtml =  inputVal + dataId;
     $('.result').html(dataId);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 5px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 20em
}

p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectstudents">
  <input type="text" class="dispIndex" name="">
  SELECT STUDENTS:<br>
  Id 1: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
  Id 2: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
  Id 3: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
  Id 4: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
 </div>
 <div class="selectstudents_result">
  <p data-id='A' class="p_names">click meA</p>
  <p data-id='B' class="p_names">click meB</p>
  <p data-id='C' class="p_names">click meC</p>
  <p data-id='D' class="p_names">click meD</p>
 </div>
    <p class='result'></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were caching the value of `$(".dispIndex").val()` on page load. Which was blank.

And you were only referencing the `dataId` in the result. `$('.result').html(dataId);`

```
function inputFocus(evename){
  $(evename).each(function(index){
    $(this).focus(function(){
      inpIndex = index;
      $('.dispIndex').val(inpIndex);
      // console.log( jQuery.type(zim_index));
    })
  });
}

inputFocus('.input_index');

$(".p_names").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
     $('.result').html($(".dispIndex").val() + $(this).data('id'));
  })
});
```

see the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/50108/)

Comment: thanks man... i never thought that on the click event  it checked blank value... thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You should append `resultHtml` in place of `dataId` to `.result` class and `inputVal = $(".dispIndex").val();` click event.

```js
function inputFocus(evename){
  $(evename).each(function(index){
    $(this).focus(function(){
      inpIndex = index;
      $('.dispIndex').val(inpIndex);
      // console.log( jQuery.type(zim_index));
    })
  });
}

inputFocus('.input_index');


$(".p_names").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    inputVal = $(".dispIndex").val();
     dataId = $(this).data('id');
     resultHtml =  inputVal + dataId;
     $('.result').html(resultHtml);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 5px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 20em
}

p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectstudents">
  <input type="text" class="dispIndex" name="">
  SELECT STUDENTS:<br>
  Id 1: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
  Id 2: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
  Id 3: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
  Id 4: <input type="text" class="input_index"><br>
 </div>
 <div class="selectstudents_result">
  <p data-id='A' class="p_names">click meA</p>
  <p data-id='B' class="p_names">click meB</p>
  <p data-id='C' class="p_names">click meC</p>
  <p data-id='D' class="p_names">click meD</p>
 </div>
    <p class='result'></p>
```

Comment: oh my gosh!.. im such a newbie.... thats the reason i got blank id coz its not on the click event... thanks a bunch man